# How to get the image currently loaded in WebBrowser control .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I got a webbrowser control in vb.net, and a page is loaded there, the page has image and I want to be able to store that image in a bitmap variable.

Can't issue any further http requestes using the image url because the image changes on each request.

the image is downlaoded in the webbrowser via HTTPS connection.

1. Tried the URLToFile thing and it didn't find the image
2. Tried the execCommand and copying to clipboard but the clipboard
   always returned Nothing.
3. Can't really take a screenshot of the image area because the
   Webbrowser control will be hidden from users on form.

Anyone?

Comment: So you are trying to work around a CAPTCHA?

Comment: No, although similar concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the perfect solution..here it goes.

Using FiddlerCore you should listen to the http/https requests made by the browser using FiddlerCore's `BeforeResponse` event.

At some point when the Webbrowser downloads the image the `BeforeResponse` will give you `Session` object with a response data `(Session.ResponseBody)` that contain the image data.

So you need to find the correct `Session` via url (also can be accessed with `Session.fullurl` and get the image data `(Session.ResponseBody)`

After that you need to convert the response data to bitmap using this:

```
 Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream
 ms.Write(ressess(ri).ResponseBody, 0, ressess(ri).ResponseBody.Length)
 currcapimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
 ms.Close()
```